# Remove duplicate objects in an array but keep add together a few properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I found a lot of answers to similar questions to this, but nothing really hit the nail on the head. I need to know how to remove duplicate objects from an array but before removing them, add some of their attributes to the original object, and I need to do this with regular JavaScript, not jQuery. For example, if I run a fast food restaurant, I want to know how many burgers I sold. Every burger sold is a Food object in an array named burger like this:

```
burger[i] = new Food(i, name, price, tax);
```

I don't need to see every single whopper I sold, so I want remove from the array all but one object with a name of whopper `burger[i].name` but I still want to know the total I sold and tax paid, so I want to add the price and the tax. Now imagine I sell more than just burgers, so my end goal is a table that would list each individual food and it's total price and tax.

Every example I've seen to remove an object from an array seems to remove the object without a chance given to add it's individual attributes to another object first. Thanks in advance, and I apologize if this is confusing or a duplicate, but I swear I've been searching for two hours for an answer for this that works.

@RayfenWindspear  @mwilson 
   Here is the object constructor I'm using:

```
    //object constructor for groups
function customGroup(id, name, count, attend, tax, sold, origID) {
    this.ID = id;
    this.cNAME = name;
    this.cCOUNT = count;
    this.cATT = attend;
    this.cTAX = tax;
    this.cSOLD = sold;
    this.cID = origID;
}//Ends function
```

The code creates two arrays of these objects using this code twice (I'm only putting it once here, the arrays created obviously have different names):

```
//loop to create objects from all groups in table 
        for (var i = 0; i < iName.length; i++) {
            name = iName[i].innerHTML;
            count = parseInt(iCount[i].innerHTML);
            //count = Number(count.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));
            attend = parseInt(iAttend[i].innerHTML);            
            tax = iTax[i].innerHTML;            
            tax = Number(tax.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));
            sold = iSold[i].innerHTML;
            sold = Number(sold.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));
            id = iID[i].innerHTML;
            tableNames[i] = new customGroup(i, name, count, attend, tax, sold, id);             
        }//ends for loop
```

Then I compare the two tables and make an array of matching objects.

```
 for (var i=0; i < tableNames.length; i++){
            for( var j=0; j < otherTableNames.length; j++){
                if (tableNames[i].cNAME == otherTableNames[j].cNAME){                   
                    count = tableNames[i].cCOUNT + otherTableNames[j].cCOUNT;
                    attend = tableNames[i].cATT + otherTableNames[j].cATT;
                    tax = tableNames[i].cTAX + otherTableNames[j].cTAX;
                    sold = tableNames[i].cSOLD + otherTableNames[j].cSOLD;
                    temp = new customGroup(j, tableNames[i].cNAME, count,        attend, tax, sold, tableNames[i].cID);                 
                    namematch.push(temp);
                }//ends if statement
            }//ends nested loop
        }//ends loop
```

Here is how I was trying to remove items with the same name but keep the original values.

```
//remove duplicate objects from namematch array   
            for (var i = 0, len = namematch.length; i < len; i++) {
                for (var j = 0, len = namematch.length; j < len2; j++) {                    
                    if (namematch[i].cNAME === namematch[j].cNAME) {                        
                        if ( i != j){
                        namematch[i].cCOUNT = namematch[i].cCOUNT + namematch[j].cCOUNT;
                        namematch[i].cATT = namematch[i].cATT + namematch[j].cATT;
                        namematch[i].cTAX = namematch[i].cTAX + namematch[j].cTAX;
                        namematch[i].cSOLD = namematch[i].cSOLD + namematch[j].cSOLD;                   
                        namematch.splice(j, 1);
                        len2=namematch.length;
                        }//ends if statement
                    }//endsif statement
                }//ends Nested loop
            }//ends forloop
```

Comment: Do you know beforehand what types of objects you will encounter, or is that out of your control?

Comment: Please paste your code so you can get a quicker/more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object for grouping the single values and if necessary, you could render a single array out of it.

```js
function Food(i, name, price, tax) {
    this.i = i;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.tax = tax;
}

var burger = [
        new Food(0, 'Hamburger', 2, 0.4),
        new Food(1, 'Cheeseburger', 2.5, 0.5),
        new Food(2, 'Hamburger', 2, 0.4),
        new Food(3, 'Cheeseburger', 2.5, 0.5),
        new Food(4, 'Hamburger', 2, 0.4),
        new Food(5, 'Cheeseburger', 2.5, 0.5),
        new Food(6, 'Cheeseburger', 2.5, 0.5),
        new Food(7, 'Hamburger', 2, 0.4),
    ],
    grouped = Object.create(null),
    result;

burger.forEach(function (food) {
    grouped[food.name] = grouped[food.name] || { name: food.name, count: 0, price: 0, tax: 0 };
    grouped[food.name].count++;
    grouped[food.name].price += food.price;
    grouped[food.name].tax += food.tax;
});

result = Object.keys(grouped).map(function (k) { return grouped[k]; });
console.log(grouped);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to do is, to take your `burger` array, [`.filter(fn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for burgers with the same name, and then [`.reduce(fn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to just a single entry.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map to hold unique items and iterate the array with a for loop. Add items if they are not in the map, if already in the map add the data you want to the existing item. When done convert the maps values back to an array.

```js
var items = [
   { type : "food1",sold : 2},
   { type : "food3",sold : 1},
   { type : "food2",sold : 3},
   { type : "food1",sold : 5},
   { type : "food3",sold : 1},
   { type : "food2",sold : 3},
   { type : "food1",sold : 5},
]
// reduce the array into a Map
var reduced = new Map();
items.forEach(item=>{ // for each item
    var red = reduced.get(item.type); // get the mapped item by the item type
    if(red !== undefined){  // is it defined
        red.sold += item.sold;  // yes add to the total
    }else{
        reduced.set(item.type,item); // no then add to the map
    }
})
items.length = 0; // empty the old array
items.push(...reduced.values()); // add the reduced items
console.log(items); // show result
```